# WordPress site homepage kept redirecting to SITE ADDRESS

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cdn

I need to put a WP site behind a 3rd party CDN, the CDN uses a private address to load pages, the private address now is IP based, let's say it's http://111.222.333.444, the site's frontend domain will be https://www.example.com.

I have configured WP's Site Address and Wordpress Address both to https://www.example.com.

But the problem is that opening the homepage will result in a dead loop. The CDN server reaches http://111.222.333.444 and it got redirected by WP to https://www.example.com (as configured in Site Address).

However other pages are fine like https://www.example.com/product/123, as I tested WordPress doesn't auto-redirect those pages when CDN reaches https://111.222.333.444/product/123 but always redirects the homepage.

How can I stop WordPress from auto-redirecting the homepage to Site Address? I have tried removing the canonical_redirect filter as suggested here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection but it didn't help.

Comment: did you try just saving the permalink preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection has been misleading, it should really be

remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');

instead of

remove_action('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');